# Give the SQL to update PEOPLE_TEST so that salary is increased by 15% for everyone born before Jan 1, 1980. Make the change permanent

Tags: sql

Give the SQL to update PEOPLE_TEST  so that salary  is increased by 15% for everyone born before  Jan 1, 1980.  Make the change permanent.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It looks like homework task... you should learn it

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume that you are working on Oracle database. Execute the following statement:

```
Update table PEOPLE_TEST 
set salary = salary * 1.15 
where truncate(dob ) <=to_date( '01011980','ddmmyyyy');
```